# How might I use a minifier as part of my rake-pipeline asset workflow

Tags: ruby, rake

Per this question: [Setting up rake-pipeline for use with handlebars alongside Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558062/setting-up-rake-pipeline-for-use-with-handlebars-alongside-google-app-engine/8564949#8564949)

I've been learning how to use rake-pipeline to manage my assets for use with ember.js (with the gracious help of dudleyf).

What I would like to know is how I might incorporate a minifier into the build process as some sort of rake-pipeline filter. Apologies as I'm not familiar with Ruby, so I might need a little more in depth explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer: use the `YUIJavaScriptCompressor`. This `Assetfile`:

```
require "rake-pipeline-web-filters"
require "rake-pipeline-web-filters/helpers"

input "assets"
output "public"

match "**/*.js" do
  yui :munge => true
end
```

will take each JavaScript file in your `assets` directory and run it through the YUI JavaScript compressor with the `munge` option. By default, it will rename each `*.js` file to `*.min.js`.