# Does Ember.js support loading external file view templates?

Tags: ember.js

I'm new to Ember/Sproutcore...
From what i could find in SproutCore documentation, SC.TemplateView supports loading handlebar template from external files. Does this functionality exist in Ember?

Answer (score 3):

As other answers have mentioned, your build tool is the key to achieving this. The following StackOverflow question shows how to do this using Rake::Pipeline [Setting up rake-pipeline for use with handlebars alongside Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558062/setting-up-rake-pipeline-for-use-with-handlebars-alongside-google-app-engine)

Regarding BPM vs. Rake::Pipeline: At the moment, the Ember.js core team is using Rake::Pipeline in their production projects. The authors of BPM have expressed interest in getting back to it, but no one is actively developing it as far as I know. That said, it's a great tool, and we're currently using it on a project.

Comment: Many of the addons have pull requests to get them working with Ember.js and BPM too... I think that's complete bs if it's true that BPM is being put on the back-burner by the core team. So who do I need to talk to about getting Ember.js and all of the [Ember.js addons](https://github.com/emberjs-addons) on [GetBPM.org](http://www.getbpm.org) and get those pull requests accepted that fixes the addons so they work with Ember.js?

Comment: @ud3323 best way to get a conversation going would probably be in the #emberjs IRC channel

Comment: Already talked to Peter about it. He said they are still in support of BPM but need some time for planning... Until then I'm just going to create Ember.js compatible packages for the addons and put them on GetBPM myself. If at a later time they want to take it over then they can.

Answer (score 0):

It's no problem to load your template from an external File. Like in SC1 this functionality is provided by your build tool which in fact translates your external files into the appropriate javascript code. One solution to do that is to make use of BPM.