# Can't create an Ember.js application using bpm

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to follow the directions on [this ud3323/bpm wiki page](https://github.com/ud3323/bpm/wiki/Using-BPM-with-Ember) to create an Ember.js application using bpm. The very first command on this page (bpm init hello_world) is throwing an exception - "No such file or directory - C:/apps/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.2.13/lib/execjs/support/which.bat" (see the issue logged [here](https://github.com/bpm/bpm/issues/93) - my comment is the second one). I checked the files under execjs directory - there is no file called which.bat. Note that I installed bpm using "gem install bpm". I don't know how to build ud3323's fork (don't know Ruby - I installed it just to try out bpm). Can anybody help me get past this issue?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: BPM is no longer actively developed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naresh,

I got some free time and found the issue. The current build of BPM requires the use of the gem execjs version 1.2.4. You probably have the latest version which is 1.3.0 or the latest from the 1.2.x branch.

What you need to do is install the correct version by running the command `gem install execjs --version 1.2.4`. After that BPM should work fine. I have it running on Windows7 64bit with a clean installation of Ruby 1.9.2.

Also for anyone else, I have detailed instructions of exactly what I did on this page: https://github.com/ud3323/bpm/wiki/Installing-with-Windows

Comment: This procedure fixes the problem with bpm throwing the "No such file or directory" exception. I can now perform several more steps in your Ember wiki page. However now running into another problem. I will start a new question for that.