# bundler: command not found: rakep --- while building emberjs todo

Tags: ruby, rake

I'm trying to build the emberjs todos from https://github.com/emberjs/todos.... While executing the command **bundle exec rakep build** , I got the following error

```
**bundler: command not found: rakep**

**Install missing gem executables with 'bundle install'**
```

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and i have included the required gems

Gems included by the bundle :

```
 * bundler (1.0.22
  * chunky_png (1.2
  * compass (0.12.2
  * fssm (0.2.9)
  * json (1.5.4)
  * rack (1.4.1)
  * rake (0.9.2.2)
  * rake-pipeline (0.6.0)
  * rake-pipeline-web-filters(0.6.0)
  * sass (3.2.1)
  * thor (0.14.6)
```

Can anyone help to trace out the bug ???

Comment: It can't find [this](https://github.com/livingsocial/rake-pipeline/blob/656ef435e6bbf55aa363ecf6142cd79721635259/bin/rakep) executable. Did you run `bundle install` like it said?

Comment: yeah i did... I followed the steps from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558062/setting-up-rake-pipeline-for-use-with-handlebars-alongside-google-app-engine    to get the bin folder and ran the bundle install command too...

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is *really old* and this is probably not a direct answer, but I ran into a similar problem trying to get the ember_phonegap_starter template up and running (it uses rakep server at some point in the webcast).

Being a complete Ruby newbie and only interested in ember.js rather than learning yet another ecosystem, I ended up cobbling together some commands based on Yuhuda Katz's answer here ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558062/setting-up-rake-pipeline-for-use-with-handlebars-alongside-google-app-engine)) and some trial and error. Someone might be able to refine this answer further. My steps on a Windows 7 machine:

1. Install Ruby 2.0.0 from the [Ruby installer](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) site.
2. Download the Ruby Development Kit.
3. Copy the development kit into the c:\ruby200 directory and run the .exe from there.
4. Open a command prompt in the c:\ruby200 directory and type:

   > ruby dk.rb init
   >
   > ruby dk.rb install
5. Now install rakep and friends:

   > gem install rake-pipeline
   >
   > gem install rake-pipeline-web-filters
   >
   > gem install rack
   >
   > gem install barber
6. At this point I was able to run rakep from the command line. I don't know that installing all those other bits are necessary for what you were trying to do.